# How to avoid Google Mail SMTP lock while traveling?

Tags: gmail, google-account, authentication, smtp

I know there are lots of articles about this problem, but I still can't find a nice way to fix that. My boss is traveling a lot, and because of constant change of place her Google account is blocked. SMTP server rejects password. CAPTCHA unlock doesn't work properly time to time and next time she flies to another place mail is locked again.

Is there any way to fix that problem for good

Maybe 2-step authentication will help?

I tried VPN account but it doesn't help as well for some reason.

- OS: OSX
- Client: Apple Mail
- Google Apps for domain

Answer (score 1):

You say you have already tried a VPN?
As I know one way would be to tunnel all here traffic through a VPN to one fixed location - thus each time she connects via SMTP it will appear she is only ever at one location.

Comment: Yes, I thought so as well, but unfortunately it didn't worked. She just moved to another location, got locked, tried VPN and it is still blocked.

Comment: Maybe it uses some kind of client id, or something like that after locking account?